Is it possible to execute an EXECUTE command from QLIK SENSE to open a VBS file that behaves like a BAT file?
I have this code in VBS that when I double click on it, it opens a URL link for me:
Option Explicit

' Declare variables
Dim url, shell

' Set the URL you want to open
url = "https://pa-qliksense.aviv.gov.il/extensions/Export_Manually/Export_Manually.html?appId=9b6006b0-e795-4112-9dff-f921b56b3210&sheetId=34be122a-f561-4320-9e9d-befaba809de3&fieldName1=%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%94&fieldValue1=%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%90%D7%9C&fieldName2&fieldValue2&fieldName3&fieldValue3&fieldName4&fieldValue4&fieldName5&fieldValue5&fieldName6&fieldValue6&fieldName7&fieldValue7&fieldName8&fieldValue8&qlikTicket=4ayN1mnB8r-aLaX3"

' Create a shell object
Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

' Open the URL in the default browser
shell.Run url

' Clean up
Set shell = Nothing

I wanted to know if there is a way to run this file through a script in QLIK SENSE?
I tried to do the EXECUTE command with routing to this VBS file but no URL link is opened for me as I expect

Probably easier is to set an external program task that executes the VBS.
If you want the script to be triggered from a Qlik script then you can create an app that calls Qlik Repository API to trigger the task.
The only thing to consided here is in the case of multi node environment. As far as im aware there is no way to "pin" the external tasks to be executed on a specific node. Because of this you have make sure that the VBS script is available on each node (in the same location)
P.S. you can check the monitor_* data connections how to call Repo API endpoints.
